# Compare two xdebug profile dumps

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I'm kind of surprised that there's no relevant results in google and here about comparing two xdebug profiler outputs.

I have two usage cases for it, a "before and after fix" to confirm the performance fix and specifically for my current problem, the difference between two hosting environments.

Has anybody done any work in this area or know of software or plugin capable of interpreting differences between two profile runs of the same workload?

As specified in the comments, it's important for me that I can do an actual comparison: **hide calls that take roughly the same amount of time and show me new or removed code paths.** Bonus points for identifying changed iterations of a loop as such rather than comparing each iteration of a loop.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/beberlei/xdebug-trace-gui ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger Well, at best that allows me to put two profiles side by side. By comparison I do mean, that I can specify a margin of x% which it'll hide from me and shows me the big changes. So if a call took 100ms and I give a margin of 10%, I only want to see that call again if it took longer than 110ms in the second dump.

Comment: Ah I see. I do not know anything like that. Maybe you can build your own ?